# Capture window when screen is off

Tags: c#, gdi+

I'm using Native GDI+ for capture window "over screen". It's not working when screen is off (generates black image). How can I fix it? (I'm using .Net 4.5)

```
public static Image CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
{
        IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);

        RECT windowRect = new RECT();
        User32.GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);

        int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
        int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;

        IntPtr hdcDest = Gdi32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
        IntPtr hBitmap = Gdi32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, width, height);

        IntPtr hOld = Gdi32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);
        Gdi32.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        Gdi32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);
        Gdi32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
        User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);

        Image image = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
        Gdi32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);

        return image;
 }
```

Comment: What version of Windows are you testing this on and is this system using monitors connected via display port connections?  I ask because display port works a lot like USB.  The system sees the monitor as an attached device and, once the monitor goes to sleep, the system considers the monitor "detached" and removes that "screen" from Windows.  Barring this, the screen being turned off really shouldn't make a difference, since the video card is still generating (and even transmitting) the image, even if the screen is not displaying it.

Comment: I have Windows 10 and Notebook.

Comment: Hmm... it's entirely possible that the screen is connected via a display-port style interface, and would even make a lot of sense in a laptop since, when the screen is off, the video card could be instructed to stop rending an image, thus conserving power. Maybe, as an experiment, have something poll and see if the IntPtr to the display device (or the device capabilities) changes at all  when the screen turns off.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know the graphics driver stops producing an image when there is no one to receive it, to save power. This might be why you can't capture the image when the screen is "off". There is no point in using CPU and GPU and BUS power on producing an image, when there is no one to receive it.